# Is this bid'ah? Is this allowed

Tags: practical-islam, islamic-philosophy, bidah, dhikr

Selam alejkum. One individual wants to make every single day 1000 dhikrs with the thought that it is practical and will be helpful to him in the afterlife and this world. For this reason every single day he says precisely 100 times  estagfirullah,   la ilahe ilallah,     ya musarrifal qulub sarrif qalbi ila ta'atik,  ya mukal libel kulubi thebit kalbi ala dinik,  la havle ve la kuvete ila bilah,   subhanallah,   subhanallahi vel-hamdu lil-lahi ve la ilahe il-lallahu vallahu ekber, alhamdulilah,  allahu ekber,  subhanallahi ve bihamdihi.  The important thing to point out is that every single day he says those dhikrs that precise number of times(100 times.)  He says it exactly that number of times(100 times) la ilahe ilallah, ja musarrifal  kulubi sarrif kalbi ila ta'atik,  estagfirullah etj... every single day without adding or subtracting.   My question is: is this bid'ah? Is this allowed?

Comment: I think [Is this thing bid'ah or is it perfectly normal and good?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/52792/is-this-thing-bidah-or-it-is-perfectly-normal-and-good/52817#52817) is relevant if not covering your issue.

Answer (score 0):

It be nafal dhikr, he is free to do as he please, do it as many times as he likes. He is free to impose his own personal goals like 100 or 1000 times. He just must remember that it is not fard to do it like that, but his personal choice to do it like that. This is not bid'ah. Now, if he believe that doing it exactly 100 times is required part of Islam, then it is bid'ah.